# How to web scrape properly in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to webscrape the following page:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Auto_Parts

Despite the fact that it works perfectly with other pages, it does not work properly for the mentioned one. It returns only the top warning box of the webpage. Any idea? I used the following code:

```
url <- 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Auto_Parts'

companyHTML <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]') %>%
  html_table(fill=TRUE)
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the infobox? Your xpath just targets the first table in the `#mw-content-text` node, which can be, but is not always, the `.infobox vcard`.

Comment: No, in essence, I need the website link in the right table.

Comment: If you're aiming for the link then I don't think your code "works perfectly" on any page. It produces a table of infobox text but no `href`s, which is where the links can be found.

Comment: hm thanks. Any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to web scrape the webpage with the RSelenium package :

```
library(RSelenium)

shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Auto_Parts')

web_Obj_Table <- remDr$findElement("xpath", '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[1]/table')
text_Table <- web_Obj_Table$getElementText()[[1]]
strsplit(text_Table, "\n")

[[1]]
 [1] "Advance Auto Parts, Inc."                                                                                                                          
 [2] "Advance Auto Parts in Cairo, Georgia"                                                                                                              
 [3] "Type Public"                                                                                                                                       
 [4] "Traded as"                                                                                                                                         
 [5] "NYSE: AAP"                                                                                                                                         
 [6] "S&P 500 component"                                                                                                                                 
 [7] "Industry Auto Parts Retail"                                                                                                                        
 [8] "Founded April 29, 1932; 90 years ago"                                                                                                              
 [9] "Founder Arthur Taubman"                                                                                                                            
[10] "Headquarters Raleigh, North Carolina, U.S."                                                                                                        
[11] "Number of locations 4,912 Advance Stores, 150 Worldpac branches and serves 1,250 independently owned Carquest branded stores (as of July 13, 2019)"
[12] "Area served United States"                                                                                                                         
[13] "Canada"                                                                                                                                            
[14] "Key people Jeffrey C. Smith"                                                                                                                       
[15] "Chair, Board of Directors"                                                                                                                         
[16] "Tom Greco (CEO, President)"                                                                                                                        
[17] "Jeff Shepherd (CFO)"                                                                                                                               
[18] "Products Replacement automotive parts & accessories"                                                                                               
[19] "Revenue US$10.11 Billion (2020)[1]"                                                                                                                
[20] "Operating income US$749.9 Million (2020)[2]"                                                                                                       
[21] "Net income US$493.02 Million (2020)[1]"                                                                                                            
[22] "Total assets US$11.84 Billion (2020)[1]"                                                                                                           
[23] "Total equity US$3.763 Billion (2020)[1]"                                                                                                           
[24] "Owner Institutional Owners[1]"                                                                                                                     
[25] "Vanguard Group Inc [2] (10.25%)"                                                                                                                   
[26] "BlackRock Fund Advisors [3] (5.18%)"                                                                                                               
[27] "Barrow, Hanley, Mewhinney & Strauss [4] (4.47%)"                                                                                                   
[28] "State Street Corp [5] (4.43%)"                                                                                                                     
[29] "Starboard Value LP [6] (4.36%)"                                                                                                                    
[30] "Number of employees 68,000[3] (2020)"                                                                                                              
[31] "Subsidiaries"                                                                                                                                      
[32] "Autopart International"                                                                                                                            
[33] "Carquest"                                                                                                                                          
[34] "Carquest Canada"                                                                                                                                   
[35] "WorldPac"                                                                                                                                          
[36] "WorldPac Canada"                                                                                                                                   
[37] "WorldPac Redline"                                                                                                                                  
[38] "Website AdvanceAutoParts.com"
```